# Settings including DataRoaming + Voice roaming - Device does not acknowledge or send error

Tags: ios, plist, mdm

According to MDM Documentation, the Data Roaming command must be as follows:

> DataRoaming Modifies the Data Roaming Setting To send a DataRoaming
>   command, the server sends a dictionary containing the following keys:
>
> **Key** **Type** **Content**
>
> Item     String      **DataRoaming**
>
> Enabled  Boolean --- If true, enables data
>   roaming. If false, disables data roaming. Enabling data roaming also
>   enables voice roaming.

In plist, a boolean value is always written as such:

> e.g `<true/>.`

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>3015</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>Settings</string>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>Item</key>
          <string>VoiceRoaming</string>
          <key>Enabled</key>
          <true />
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>Item</key>
          <string>DataRoaming</string>
          <key>Enabled</key>
          <true />
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The problem is the iOS does not send back acknowledged or error and I do not know what is wrong with my XML. Anything I am not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>3038</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>Settings</string>
      **<key>Settings</key>**
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>Item</key>
          <string>VoiceRoaming</string>
          <key>Enabled</key>
          <true />
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>Item</key>
          <string>DataRoaming</string>
          <key>Enabled</key>
          <false />
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I have found the solution, I was forgetting the key - Settings.